# iOS : Load uiview of another view controller

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewcontroller` on which I am showing UIview which contains a registration form.
now I need this same registration form on another `UIViewcontroller` without recreating the same for second UIViewcontroller.

I am using UInavigationcontroller.

Is there any way to achieve this? I am stuck since last few hours and tried everything.

Comment: [View Controller Containment](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html)

Comment: Option 1: put the common functionality in a different class and inherit from that one both of the view controllers. Option 2: put the common functionality in a help class and use that class (if you define them static) or object in the 2 view controllers. You will run into a little problem if you want to reuse the GUI design (I still did not figured out how to do it properly with Storyboard).

Comment: @Abizern : It works only if view is main view but in my case view to be added is nested inside.

Comment: No, that's what containment is all about. You add the controller as a child of the main view controller, and then you add it's view as a subview.

Comment: @alinoz You use a "Container View" which creates an associated View Controller in the storyboard - and which also takes care of adding this associated VC as a child VC. A very simple example I just created https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/585261/Containers.zip

Answer (score 0):

First method & the one that I will prefer is to create the `registration form` as a separate `UIView` class.

Then you can use it in various `view controllers` as `subview`.

Second method, you can create a `parent class` & inherit both the classes from this `parent class`. This parent class will contain all the common functionalities.(as mentioned by @alinoz).

Comment: but seperate UIView class will just have functionality and not UI part. So i will have to recreate UI part

Answer (score -1):

You can add `viewController` in another view controller. Create instance of `registretionViewController` and add its view in current `viewcontroller` vew. `[self.view addSubview:regViewController.view]`. And if you want to push this you can simple create instance of it and push in navigation stack.

Comment: UIViewController containment is a better idea, I'm not even sure your code will compile cleanly without it.

Comment: If you need same view as part of any other view controller, then I think this is good option to create an instance and add view as subview. the code above will not the whole but Its a way to solve the problem

Comment: Why negative vote, adding view of viewcontroller as subview is view containment.

Answer (score -1):

Let the class of your registration form view be RegisterFormView.

In **appDelegate** create a class public property of RegisterFormView.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) RegisterFormView *formView;
```

When you first create form view in viewController A, assign the same in appDelegate also.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.formView = registrationFormViewInstance;
```

In another view controller(B) where you want to use the same formView,

```
if([UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.formView != nil){
   //use the form view
}
```

Comment: The app delegate is not some convenient singleton you can use to store arbitrary references.

Comment: @Abizern what? application Delegate is only one.And it kinds acts like singleton, why cant he use it, unless he specified that he don't want to touch appDelegate. Please explain ..?

Comment: I should have been clearer - The Application delegate __is not meant__ to be used as some convenient singleton that is used to store arbitrary references.